# Tkinter button function does not work as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

**What I Am Doing:**

I am writing a "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game in Tkinter. What I do exactly right now is that I am writing a function (or 2 rather) that ungrids buttons except for the one being pushed. That part is working so far but I also want them to reappear upon clicking the same button again.

The code throws no error of any kind. It is just that the buttons aren't being re-placed upon clicking the chosen button again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**The Code:**

```
import tkinter
# from tkinter import *


# ||create a class for game windows;
class GameWindow:

    # set attributes; window height and width;
    window_height = 525
    window_width = 700

    # create __init__ function; self and window_name as parameter;
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        # make Tk() master of this class;
        self.master = tkinter.Tk()
        # set title of the file to the value of 'window_name';
        self.master.title(window_name)
        # create a static grid by assigning weight to all rows and columns;
        self.rows = 0  # -- create row counter --;
        while self.rows < 10:  # -- make row counter count up to 9 --;
            self.master.rowconfigure(self.rows, weight=1)  # -- assign weight of 1 to respective row --;
            self.master.columnconfigure(self.rows, weight=1)  # -- assign weight of 1 to respective column --;
            self.rows += 1  # -- increment of 1 the row counter --;
        # save screen width and height in variables;
        width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        # calculate centered window offset coordinates and save them in respective variables;
        pos_x = (width - self.window_width) // 2
        pos_y = (height - self.window_height) // 2
        # make main window resizable;
        self.master.resizable()
        # initiate geometry manager with aforementioned values;
        self.master.geometry(f"{self.window_width}x{self.window_height}+{pos_x}+{pos_y}")

    # create function to execute the window in within the mainloop;
    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()


# create a standard class for choice buttons;
class ChoiceButton:

    # set class attributes
    is_active = False
    is_removed = False
    row_coord = ""
    column_coord = ""
    rowspan_coord = ""
    columnspan_coord = ""
    sticky_parameter = ""
    button_List = []

    # create __init__ function; declare parameters for initialization of name, status, color;
    def __init__(self, parent, init_name, init_status, init_color, init_row, init_column, init_rowspan, init_columnspan,
                 init_sticky):
        # implement tkinter Button through instance variable "master"
        self.master = tkinter.Button(parent, text=init_name, bg=init_color, command=self.button_click)
        # assign values to class attributes
        self.is_active = init_status
        self.row_coord = init_row
        self.column_coord = init_column
        self.rowspan_coord = init_rowspan
        self.columnspan_coord = init_columnspan
        self.sticky_parameter = init_sticky
        self.button_List.append(self)

    # create function to re-grid inactive buttons;
    def recover_button(self):
        # check if buttons in list are removed, if yes, grid them at specified coordinates;
        for button in self.button_List:
            if button.is_removed:
                button.master.grid(row=button.row_coord, column=button.column_coord, rowspan=button.rowspan_coord, columnspan=button.columnspan_coord,
                                   sticky=button.sticky_parameter)

    # create function to define what happens when you click a button;
    def button_click(self):
        # if button inactive when clicked, set to active, bg to grey and deactivate all other buttons in list;
        if not self.is_active:
            self.is_active = True
            self.master.config(bg="Grey")
            for button in self.button_List:
                if button != self:
                    self.is_removed = True
                    button.master.grid_forget()
        # if button inactive when clicked, set to inactive, bg to white and execute recover_button function;
        else:
            self.is_active = False
            self.master.config(bg="White")
            self.recover_button()


# create main menu window from GameWindow Composition Class; Set title by passing window_name parameter;
main_Menu = GameWindow("Rock, Paper, Scissors! - Main Menu")
# instantiate buttons from ChoiceButtons Composition Class;
rock_Button = ChoiceButton(main_Menu.master, "Rock", False, "White", 1, 1, 1, 2, "nsew")  # rock button;
paper_Button = ChoiceButton(main_Menu.master, "Paper", False, "White", 1, 4, 1, 2, "nsew")  # paper button;
scissors_Button = ChoiceButton(main_Menu.master, "Scissors", False, "White", 1, 7, 1, 2, "nsew")  # scissors button;
# grid each of the buttons;
rock_Button.master.grid(row=rock_Button.row_coord, column=rock_Button.column_coord, rowspan=rock_Button.rowspan_coord,
                        columnspan=rock_Button.columnspan_coord, sticky=rock_Button.sticky_parameter)
paper_Button.master.grid(row=paper_Button.row_coord, column=paper_Button.column_coord, rowspan=paper_Button.rowspan_coord,
                         columnspan=paper_Button.columnspan_coord, sticky=paper_Button.sticky_parameter)
scissors_Button.master.grid(row=scissors_Button.row_coord, column=scissors_Button.column_coord,
                            rowspan=scissors_Button.rowspan_coord, columnspan=scissors_Button.columnspan_coord,
                            sticky=scissors_Button.sticky_parameter)


print(ChoiceButton.button_List)
main_Menu.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `button_click` function, in the for loop it should be

```
if button != self:
    button.is_removed = True
    button.master.grid_forget()
```

instead of `self.is_removed = True`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, that did solve it! Its always those careless mistakes that are the hardest to find if you make them yourself lol.
I 10x checked my logic but it checked out. Really got desperate there.

Thanks again for solving it, it nearly drove me insane!

Comment: You are welcome! Those mistakes are indeed hard to find. Sometimes I find it helpful to just leave it and come back on the next day... Anyways good luck on your game!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, that is usually a good plan of action. The solution comes to your mind either the day after or - in my case usually - right when I am about to fall asleep haha.